# back to previous page gui

Tags: java, swing, jframe

if i have add a number and i print it in a new page(JFrame). now, i want to get back to

previous page to add another number.

how to write the code? because i want to keep thw new page open and back to previous page. the

new page is to display what the number that have been added by the user. totally no idea with

it.

i've try this

first frame called 'frame1'

second frame called 'frame2'

```
   public static boolean isClicked = true;
   if(btnOK.equals(isClicked))
     {
         frame2.setVisible(true);
         frame1.setVisible(false);
     }
```

Comment: I do not understand the question, sorry

Comment: back to previous page to add a new number

Comment: Keeping open a page supposed to default to implement workflow on actions imposed a business logic.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your actual problem, but maybe you should take a look at Dialogs in Java, especially the modality of Dialogs.

Answer (score 3):

1) The use of multiple `JFrame`s in Java is a bad practice see here:

- [The Use of Multiple JFrames: Good or Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)

2) I would suggest using a `LayoutManager` like `CardLayout` which allows you to flip between containers like `JPanel`s on a single `JFrame`:

- [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

3) You might also want to substitute your initial `JFrame` for a `JDialog`/`JOptionPane`, but that would depend on the usage of the initial `JFrame`.